# Laravel form returns, 500 Server Error on a shared Host

Tags: laravel, forms, hosting, host, shared-hosting

I just uploaded a Laravel (8) project to a host, and the page looks good, it takes the data from the database, displays them, and I even have an administrator section where I can delete and edit things in the database, but when I want to go to a view with a form to add things to the database I get "500 | Server Error".

Why can this be? How can I solve it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please add the log file of your laravel app to this question otherwise this is not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 could appear from having the server's PHP version lower than the minimum version requirement by Laravel.

From my experience, the problem came out when Laravel requires a higher PHP version, if you upgrade your PHP the problem will be solved.

Make sure your server's PHP version is equal to or higher than what your Laravel version needs.